# Annotation with Spring @Value Meta-annotation not injecting the value

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Having a properties file and the necessary `context:properties-placeholder` configuration...

```
someproperty=somevalue
```

In a Spring bean we could have:

```
@Value("${someproperty}")
private String someProperty;
```

Where someProperties value would be `"somevalue"`.

I want to create a new annotation `@Refreshable` with `@Value` as meta annotation so that it behaves the same as using `@Value` directly. Since `@Value` requires a value I hardcode `"default"` hoping that `@Refreshable's value()` will override it:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Value("default")
public @interface Refreshable {
    String value();
}
```

Then when I use the new annotation in a bean, I was expecting it to work properly, injecting the declared value `"somevalue"`:

```
@Refreshable("${someproperty}")
private String someProperty;
```

But I don't get `${someproperty}`'s value, but "default". Ideas?

Comment: You using this Value to set value on your annotation org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value. Rather it should be like this for default value -> public String value() default "default";

Comment: The point is that I don't mind the initialized "default" value. It's only there so that `public @interface Refreshable` compiles without errors. What I really want is that it's value comes from the actual use of the new annotation `@Refreshable("${someproperty}")`. However, with this, the ${someproperty} placeholder isn't resolved.

Comment: Can you put your complete code showing how you config/printing value of someProperty, should be some init issue only.

Comment: This is currently not supported, good news is tha has been scheduled for 4.3.0: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved in 4.3.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT. To override @Value's value is necessary to use `@AliasFor`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Value("")
public @interface Refreshable {

    @AliasFor(annotation=Value.class, attribute="value")
    String value();
}
```